# Suggest how to write a text file which is available in SFTP location

Tags: java, file, sftp, jsch

1.Class A is my main exactly i want write all my result in .txt which is available in sftp location.

2.In  class B i have created .txt file in the sftp location in that same text file i want to put my print values.

3.Below code it testNg code

```
@Test
public  class   A
       {

 B b = new B();
    int i=10;
int j = 20;
int k=i+j;

 System.out.println(k);
   
}
}    
    
    
    
public class B
{   
    
       public String sftrWriteFile() {
                try {
                    connect();
                    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
                    channelSftp.connect();
                    System.out.println("Session connected  " + session.isConnected());
                    //fileOutStream = channelSftp.put("/home/dasrsoum/RM_Test_Result.xlsx");
                    
                    fileOutStream = channelSftp.put("/home/dasrsoum/RM_Test_Result.xlsx");
                    
                    // wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileStream);
                    // sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    fileOutStream.close();
                    session.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "Sucess";
            }
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain your problem. What happens, what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PrintWriter` decorator to `OutputStream` to simplify writing to a text file. Let's assume that you are passing `int[] data` to `sftrWriteFile()` method of class B i.e. the signature changes as `sftrWriteFile(int data)`. Following code snippet will help you to understand the idea:

```
            OutputStream fileOutStream = channelSftp.put("/home/dasrsoum/RM_Test_Result.txt");
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileOutStream, true);
            for (int value : data) {
                printWriter.println(value);
            }
            printWriter.close();
```